# Getting element from a certain numpy array returned from OpenCV?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, element

I am trying to get information (coordinates) that is within a numpy array and I am having a difficult time extracting information from it.

The numpy array was returned by an openCV method, cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK, which produced coordinates of each point in a numpy array.

This is the output for a single point:

```
[[[ 292.61154175  264.74569702]]]
```

Small sample of the code:

```
p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

good_new = p1[st==1]
good_old = p0[st==1]
```

How do I extract those numbers individually from that type of numpy array?

Comment: What's exactly the problem? To obtain individual values from nested lists/arrays like `[[[ 292.61154175  264.74569702]]]`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the individual numbers from the array where I can individually get 292.61154175 and 264.7459702.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy

# create such a nested array
d = numpy.array([[[1, 2]]])

# test that we can access individual elements
assert d[0, 0, 0] == 1
assert d[0, 0, 1] == 2
```

UPDATE:

Please note that the above indexing works only with numpy arrays. The standard Python nested lists like `e = [[[1, 2]]]` must be indexed in the standard Python way: `e[0][0][0]`.

Comment: Please access numpy arrays as `d[0, 0, 0]` instead of `d[0][0][0]`.